# SQL select rows with max value from database and group by 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, max, left-join

I have this table:

TABLE offers

```
 +------+--------------+----------+----------------+
 | id   | player_id    | team_id  | valore         |
 +------+--------------+----------+----------------+
 | 1    | 1            | 1        | 230            |
 | 2    | 1            | 3        | 150            |
 | 3    | 9            | 3        | 150            |
 | 4    | 1            | 5        | 100            |
 | 5    | 7            | 5        | 37             |
 | 6    | 7            | 1        | 38             |
 +------+--------------+----------+----------------+
```

And I expect this results, 
I would like to create a view like this:

```
+------+--------------+----------+----------------+
| id   | player_id    | team_id  | valore         |
+------+--------------+----------+----------------+
| 1    | 1            | 1        | 230            |
| 3    | 9            | 3        | 150            |
| 6    | 7            | 1        | 38             |
+------+--------------+----------+----------------+
```

I try with this SQL CODE:

create view...

```
select t1.* 
  from offers t1
       left join ( select player_id, 
                          team_id, 
                          max(valore) as valore
                     from offers
                 group by player_id, 
                          team_id) t2 
                 on t1.player_id = t2.player_id 
                    and t1.team_id = t2.team_id 
                    and t1.valore = t2.valore
```

But the results is the same of first table...It does not change anything.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You never have to be sorry for the grammar of a language you are learning or can't speak fluent. As long as you are trying and improve, its ok. Also, why exactly do you match `valore`

Comment: thx.Valore is a value of offer for player with id_player 1..2..

Comment: you want max of valore for each player_id

Comment: yes, for each player, team_id is the id of a team who made the offer 
and serves for the update of other table

Comment: If your product_id for 2 rows are same and valore is also same but team id is different then what should happen? shall it show 1 row or 2 rows ?

Comment: well....who first put offer...i have timestamp column also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected result doesn't suggests `team_id` in `GROUP BY` clause, it is actually based on `player_id`. So, remove it from `GROUP BY` clause & change the `ON` clause to `t1.player_id = t2.player_id and t1.valore = t2.valore`

So, Your query would be  :

```
create view...
    select t1.*  
    from offers t1 inner join 
        (select player_id, max(valore) as valore
         from offers
         group by player_id
        ) t2 
       on t1.player_id = t2.player_id and
          t1.valore = t2.valore;
```

However, i would do instead :

```
create view v1 as
    select o.*
    from offers o
    where valore = (select max(o1.valore)
                    from offer o1
                    where o1.player_id = o.player_id
                   );
```

Comment: Left join returns additional columns with NULLs, INNER JOIN looks fine here